# sfJQueryUIPlugin: No Picker for new records

Tags: symfony1, datepicker, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Everyday is a new day with Symfony, but I'm loving it!
This morning I installed the `sfJQueryUIPlugin`. It has very little dependencies & accepts themeRoller styles. However, it has 2 issues:

[Feature_Request] There is no way to specify the year range. By default, it shows a 20 year range around the year in the field value. eg. if field value is 1993-01-20, the range will be 1983 to 2003.
??? Has anyone found a way out???

The DatePicker does not appear when the field is empty, Thus it does not show up during new record creation.
To solve this, I tried setting up the default value in the date input field (which now appears as a `text` input) using `$this->setDefault('date_of_birth',date('Y-m-d'));`
??? Is anybody facing this problem of picker now available during new record creation ???
??? Also is it the right way to set default value ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already logged the feature request and the bug. Just want to know if someone else is facing this problem? and has found a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the date picker on the new registration form, I had to `include javascripts` in the indexSuccess template of my form (my fault)

as for the year range, I modified the plugin file to include additional parameter

```
class sfWidgetFormDateJQueryUI extends sfWidgetForm
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {

    if(sfContext::hasInstance())
     $this->addOption('culture', sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture());
    else
     $this->addOption('culture', "en");
    $this->addOption('change_month',  false);
    $this->addOption('change_year',  false);
    $this->addOption('number_of_months', 1);
    $this->addOption('show_button_panel',  false);
    $this->addOption('theme', '/sfJQueryUIPlugin/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css');
    $this->addOption('year_range', '-30:+0');
    parent::configure($options, $attributes);
  }

  public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
  {
    $attributes = $this->getAttributes();

    $input = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), $attributes);

    $html = $input->render($name, $value);

    $id = $input->generateId($name);
    $culture = $this->getOption('culture');
    $cm = $this->getOption("change_month") ? "true" : "false";
    $cy = $this->getOption("change_year") ? "true" : "false";
    $nom = $this->getOption("number_of_months");
    $sbp = $this->getOption("show_button_panel") ? "true" : "false";
    $yrs = $this->getOption("year_range");

    if ($culture!='en')
    {
    $html .= <<<EOHTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var params = $.datepicker.regional['$culture'];
    params.changeMonth = $cm;
    params.changeYear = $cy;
    params.numberOfMonths = $nom;
    params.showButtonPanel = $sbp;
    params.yearRange = "$yrs";
    $("#$id").datepicker(params);
    });
</script>
EOHTML;
    }
    else
    {
    $html .= <<<EOHTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var params = {
    changeMonth : $cm,
    changeYear : $cy,
    numberOfMonths : $nom,
    showButtonPanel : $sbp,
    yearRange : "$yrs"
        };
    $("#$id").datepicker(params);
    });
</script>
EOHTML;
    }

    return $html;
  }

  public function getStylesheets()
  {...
  }

  public function getJavaScripts()
  {...
  }

}
```

and setup the widget as:

```
$this->widgetSchema['date_of_birth']= new sfWidgetFormDateJQueryUI(array("change_month" => true, "change_year" => true, "theme" => "smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css", "year_range" => "-30:+0"));
```